# how to print mached regex in perl

Tags: regex, perl

i have some line like this:

```
Activity:B2012-0002            Type:BLDG            Sub Type:SFD_OTHE           Status:ISSUED
```

and i want to print only:

```
Activity:B2012-0002
```

for that i use next code:

```
my $text_file = "homework.txt";

open(INPUT, '<',$text_file) or die $!;
        while(my $row = <INPUT>){
            chomp($row);
            if($row =~ /Activity:[\w-]+/){
               print "$1\n";
            }
        }
```

but this code return next error:

```
Use of uninitialized value $var in print at test.pl line 13, <INPUT> line 1.
```

i need a little help,
thx:)

Comment: `$1` refers to Group 1, but your regex has no capturing groups, use `/(Activity:[\w-]+)/`. There is also `$&`  placeholder if you do not want to use capturing groups (use `print "$&\n"`).

Comment: Use this hope it will help: `(Activity:[\w-]+)`

Comment: There is no such variable `$var` in your code. So the error message cannot come from the code you posted. Please [edit] your post and post the real code and the real error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add capture groups to your regex. E.g. brackets around what you want to capture.

```
        if($row =~ /Activity:([\w-]+)/){
           print "$1\n";
        }
```

Will print:

```
B2012-0002
```

Incidentally - if all your doing is capturing, you might want to not bother assigning `$row`. Decide if this makes your code clearer:

```
while ( <INPUT> ) {
  if ( m/Activity:([\w-]+)/){
    print "$1\n";
  }
}
```

Or perhaps even:

```
m/Activity:([\w-]+)/ && print $1,"\n";
```